# Unable to install scikits.audiolab

Tags: python, scikits

I need to install scikits.audiolab 0.11.0 on Mac. I installed libsndfile using homebrew, following these instructions from a previous thread:

1- Install Homebrew (paste this on a terminal):

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

2- Install libsnd:

```
brew install libsndfile
```

3- Link libsnd:

```
brew link --overwrite libsndfile
```

4- Install scikits.audiolab:

```
sudo easy_install scikits.audiolab
```

However pycharm still does not recognise audiolab when I attempt to import it. Now i get a different error: 
scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11168:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'

I am running python 3.7

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please don't `sudo easy_install` stuff. That's a good way to break your Python installation (and OS if it depends on that installation). Use virtual environments instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try installing via download files instead of the terminal. I faced a simillar issue while installing graphviz via terminal. But worked out via download files.

Here is the link for scikits.audiolab download files:
Click [here]: https://pypi.org/project/scikits.audiolab/#files

Comment: Okay thanks. I have downloaded the files. How do I then install from the downloaded files?